# How can I make Rails create my test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get Rails 7 to create my test database:

```
bin/rails db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test
```

I have very clearly set up my test environment in `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  port:     5432
  pool:     5
  host:     localhost
  database: my_db_dev
  username: user
  password: pwd

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_test

production:
  <<: *default
```

But the command is trying to delete my development database:

```
base) ➜  git:(main) ✗ bin/rails db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "my_db_dev" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 3 other sessions using the database.


Caused by:
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "my_db_dev" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 3 other sessions using the database.

Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What am I missing about the environment setting? I've even run:

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

but that doesn't appear to have done anything.

Comment: Check if `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is set. If set it overrides any settings from the database.yml file.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: This worked max! Please put your answer as an answer so I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:test:prepare
```

Sometimes we need to specify the environment before running any of the commands

Answer (score 1):

`ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is merged with and overrides any settings from the database.yml file.

This is often used in production environments like Heroku to avoid checking in credentials.

See:

- [3.19 Configuring a Database](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```

As I know `db:test:prepare` is [no longer available since Rails 4.1.0.rc1+](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/936).